# Custom Permalink For Custom Post Type - Working Fine But Broken For Pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, filters, url-rewriting

I'm having an issue with pagination not working while trying to get custom post type permalink. I've Custom post type 'songs' and custom taxonomy 'singer' here:

`example.com/songs/`              // Custom Post Type

`example.com/singer/`             // Custom Taxonomy

`example.com/songs/article`       // Post Permalink

I want it to look like

`example.com/singer/article`       /// site.com/custom-taxonomy/post

here is my Custom Post Type Code

```
add_action( 'init', 'your_prefix_register_post_type' );
function your_prefix_register_post_type() {
    $labels = [
        'name'                     => esc_html__( 'Songs', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'            => esc_html__( 'Song', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'                  => esc_html__( 'Add New', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'             => esc_html__( 'Add new song', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'                => esc_html__( 'Edit Song', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'                 => esc_html__( 'New Song', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'                => esc_html__( 'View Song', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'view_items'               => esc_html__( 'View Songs', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'             => esc_html__( 'Search Songs', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'                => esc_html__( 'No songs found', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'       => esc_html__( 'No songs found in Trash', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'        => esc_html__( 'Parent Song:', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'                => esc_html__( 'All Songs', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'archives'                 => esc_html__( 'Song Archives', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'attributes'               => esc_html__( 'Song Attributes', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item'         => esc_html__( 'Insert into song', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item'    => esc_html__( 'Uploaded to this song', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'featured_image'           => esc_html__( 'Featured image', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image'       => esc_html__( 'Set featured image', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image'    => esc_html__( 'Remove featured image', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image'       => esc_html__( 'Use as featured image', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'                => esc_html__( 'Songs', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list'        => esc_html__( 'Filter songs list', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'filter_by_date'           => esc_html__( '', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'    => esc_html__( 'Songs list navigation', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'items_list'               => esc_html__( 'Songs list', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'item_published'           => esc_html__( 'Song published', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'item_published_privately' => esc_html__( 'Song published privately', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'item_reverted_to_draft'   => esc_html__( 'Song reverted to draft', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'item_scheduled'           => esc_html__( 'Song scheduled', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'item_updated'             => esc_html__( 'Song updated', 'your-textdomain' ),
    ];
    $args = [
        'label'               => esc_html__( 'Songs', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'delete_with_user'    => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'rest_base'           => '',
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => '',
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-audio',
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'supports'            => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'],
        'taxonomies'          => ['singer', 'rapper', 'category', 'movie', 'album', 'composer', 'lyricist', 'by-year', 'mood', 'file-link', 'post-id', 'yt_id', 'artist'],
        'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'songs'),
    ];

    register_post_type( 'songs', $args );
}
```

And Code to rewrite slug for post permalink

```
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'singer' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '/songs/' , '/' . $terms[0]->slug . '/' , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_course_post_link', 1, 3 );

function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(.*)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=songs&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
```

thank you ahead for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// change in post type argument
register_post_type(
             "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "songs/%singer%",
 //change in taxonomy argument                         "with_front" => true ]);
 register_taxonomy(
                    'rewrite' =>false',
                    'with_front' => true,
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'Custom Rewrite Slug' => '');
// for add rewrite rule
function so23698827_add_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
  $new = array();
  $new['songs/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?songs=$matches[2]';
  $new['songs/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?singer=$matches[1]';

  return array_merge( $new, $rules ); // Ensure our rules come first
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'so23698827_add_rewrite_rules' );

// for permalinks
function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'songs' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'singer' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%singer%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
        else{
           return str_replace( '%singer%/' , '' , $post_link ); 
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 3 );
```

Hope this is helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sir I've tried but the result I got changed singer permalink also and the song URL is not as I required. As the solution, a single song link is like 
```example.com/song/singer/song-name/```
the required URL pattern is
```exapmle.com/singer/song-name/```   Suggest If anything else I could do, that could be better, thanks in advance.

Comment: is page show error 404 ?

Comment: The pattern you provide is giving me URL as ```example.com/song/singer/song-name/``` but I don't need that's pattern bro I want to remove the post type slug and add custom taxonomy before the post URL. Also tried patterns and working fine for single song URL  are ```example .com/songs/singer/song-name``` and ```example .com/song-name``` but when I try to get URL as ```example .com/singer/song-name``` all my pagination got broken or got 404 on single song URL

Comment: oky i try to find and try to make pattern which you want if i got i post here : )

Comment: Thanks, @MR. shaikh__92